# Error in Syntax of FROM clause

Tags: c#, sql

Here is my code that I thought worked but it continues to give me a syntax error in my `FROM` clause. Could someone help me understand what I am missing? Without the `try\catch`, it highlights the line `int result = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();`.

```
string constring = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\jwhite\Documents\TrainingDB.accdb";
string cmdText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM USER WHERE Username=@p1 AND [Password]=@p2";
using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constring))
using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdText, con))
{
   try
   {
      con.Open();
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", textBox1.Text);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", textBox2.Text);
      int result = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
      if (result > 0)
      {
         groupBox1.Visible = false;
         groupBox2.Visible = true;
         string commandText = "SELECT RIGHTS FROM USER WHERE Username=@p1 and [Password]=@p2";
         using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(commandText, con))
         {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", textBox1.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", textBox2.Text);
            string query = (string)command.ExecuteScalar();
            {
               if (query == "Administrator")
               {
                  toolStripMenuItem59.Enabled = true;
                  administratorToolStripMenuItem1.Enabled = true;
                  administratorToolStripMenuItem3.Enabled = true;
                  administratorToolStripMenuItem4.Enabled = true;
                  administratorToolStripMenuItem5.Enabled = true;
                  administratorToolStripMenuItem2.Enabled = true;
                  administratorToolStripMenuItem6.Enabled = true;
                  toolStripMenuItem92.Enabled = true;
                  toolStripMenuItem108.Enabled = true;
               }
            }
         }
      }
      else
         MessageBox.Show("Invalid Credentials, Please Try Again");
   }

   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      MessageBox.Show("Failed due to " + ex.Message);
   }
}
```

Comment: What is the actual exception message that you're getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `USER` write `[USER]` as [**USER**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186738.aspx) is a reserved word.

See List of Reserved Words [**HERE**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx)

Comment: Awesome thank you that worked! I will mark this answered as soon as it lets me.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters.aspx OleDbCommand does not support named parameter

> The OLE DB .NET Provider does not support named parameters for passing
>   parameters to an SQL statement or a stored procedure called by an
>   OleDbCommand when CommandType is set to Text. In this case, the
>   question mark (?) placeholder must be used. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID = ?
```

Therefore, the order in which OleDbParameter objects are added to the OleDbParameterCollection must directly correspond to the position of the question mark placeholder for the parameter in the command text.

So order of parameter is important.